# How to make ListView update at background and not freez UI when ItemsSource updated?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm, binding

I have a ListView:

```
 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Students, IsAsync=True}">             
     <ListView.View>
         <GridView>
             <!--Some view things -->
         </GridView>
     </ListView.View>
 </ListView>
```

and this is `Students` in my ViewModel:

```
public ICollection<Student> Students
{
    get
    {
        return _students;

    }
    set
    {
        _students = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(() => this.Students);
    }
}
```

I'm updating `Students` in some tasks like this (and I'm updating `SourceState` when user chooses something in another TreeView):

```
private State _sourceState;

public State SourceState
{
    get
    {
        return _sourceState;
    }
    set
    {
        _sourceState = value;
        OnSourceStateChanged();
        OnPropertyChanged(() => this.SourceState);
    }
}

private void OnSourceStateChanged()
{
    Task updateStudentFromSourceStateTask = new Task(() =>
    {
        Students = _stateService.GetAllStudents(_sourceState);
    });

    updateStudentFromSourceStateTask.Start();
}
```

the problem is whenever something changes `Students`, the UI freezes until ListView shows data in new `Students` and I don't know how can I tell ListView to refresh it's data in background thread (I've tried `IsAsync=True` in binding but it didn't help)

Comment: You're replacing the entire collection at a go, which could impact UI performance.  How about you switch it to an ObservableCollection with student instances that implement INPC.  Then, when you wish to update them, you can iterate through the list of old and new and update as needed (property values, remove an instance, add a new one, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was happening because I'm using `Mahapps.Metro` and it made ListView not to use `VirtualizingStackPanel`

The problem solved by using `Style="{DynamicResource VirtualisedMetroListView}`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use "virtualizing".

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Students}">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>

    <ListView.Resources>
         <DataTemplate DataType="...">
             <Grid>
                    ...
<ListView/>
```

**Edit**:

Maybe your problem is in type of source and how you evaluate it. In specific case where I did use it my source was declared like this:

```
    public IEnumerable<MyElementType> Elements
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable<MyElementType>)GetValue(ElementsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ElementsProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ElementsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Elements", typeof(IEnumerable<MyElementType>), typeof(MyUiUserControlType), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
```

And refresh happened when I apply new filter to bigger massive. Virtualizing will display and allow to start using your list immediately when all elements that must be actually visible, are populated. 
Your problem might be in using ICollection. But that already depends on your code-behind requirements.

Comment: In that case it's not filling of ListView that freezes UI. Probably populating of your source itself.

Comment: if i remove `ItemsSource="{Binding Students}"` nothing freezes

Comment: I'm using `INotifyPropertyChanged`